# phpMyAdmin MySQL Database - Reset auto increment number on existing table and re-apply from beginning

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with existing data that has a unique and auto increment key column named "_id" and several other columns and because this was a test database, I deleted some random rows and would like to reset my _id column to 1 and auto fill the existing _id rows automatically by adding +1 (same as auto increment). It will be easier if I explain using images, please see below:

[image]

Next inserted row will auto increment _id to "6".

Answer (score 0):

please try following sql:
ALTER TABLE "tablename" AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: Even if you set `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`, it will automatically increase to the `MAX(_id)+1` anyway. Auto-increment will never generate a new value less than the greatest existing value. So it won't fill in the gaps.